# EF Core Navigation property not loaded even after using include

Tags: ef-core-2.0

Here is my db design

[image]

For this I am retrieving the data through following query in EF Core.

```
from u in _context.Users
                       from r in _context.Roles.Include("RoleApplicationActivity")
                       from raa in _context.RoleAppActivities.Include("Application").Include("Activity").Include("Role")
                       from app in _context.Applications.Include(a => a.RoleApplicationActivity)
                       from ac in _context.Activities.Include(a => a.RoleApplicationActivity)
                       where u.Id == id
                       select new FullUser
                       {
                           User = u,
                           Roles = u.Roles,
                           RoleAppActivity = r.RoleApplicationActivity

                       }
```

Even after using includes when i check the values for navigation property they are empty. wondering what I am missing. Help appreciated.

Before I run this query if load all the required entities then EF Core is populating the data for me. Wondering if it is good way to do it.

```
_context.Applications.Load();
_context.Roles.Load();
_context.Activities.Load();
```

[image]